# GIT push clone to master

Tags: git

I'm new to GIT. I've been reading/playing and really enjoying it.

However everything works perfectly up until when it comes time to push the changes on the clone to the master.

Here's my current workflow.

**Init existing application.**

```
cd /var/www/app

git init
git add .
git commit -m "my first"
```

**Create new directory and clone the master.**

```
mkdir /var/www/apptest && cd "$_"

git clone /var/www/app .
```

**Create new branch, modify and merge back to clone.**

```
git checkout -b fix

echo "hello" > test.txt

git add test.txt
git commit -a -m "added test file"

git checkout master
git merge fix
```

**Everything appears ok.**

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

**Here's where it all falls apart, trying to push clone back to master.**

```
git push origin master
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/var/www/app/'

git push origin/master
fatal: 'origin/master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? I have read some things where people say you need to delete the original master and push the clone. That seems crazy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/www/app` needs to be a bare repo. You cannot git push to a non-bare repo.

So, the beginning of the workflow will be like this

`cd /var/www/app
git init --bare`

And then you can continue with the rest of your workflow.

Comment: thanks for the response however its a no go...

`fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: No such device`

From reading it says I cant use it as I have a config folder in that directory :(

Answer (score 0):

**A comment:**  Call the current repo the **local repo** (rather than a clone), and the original repo you cloned from a **remote**, definitely not a master (which is the default name for the main branch).  Those are the standard terms to help avoid confusion.

That being said,

The issue is that the remote (`app` repo at `/var/www/app`) has a working directory (is not a bare repo), and has master currently checked out.  Here is the message that is being reported in my version of Git (2.13.3.windows.1):

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: the work tree to HEAD.
remote:
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
remote: to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: other way.
remote:
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

So there are a few options:

1. If your intent is to make the `app` repo as a permanent remote repo (i.e. a repo intended to serve as a central repo for multiple team members or as a backup only), then use `git init --bare` to initialize it without a working directory (then `apps` will have the same content as you would normally find in `apps/.git`.  This is why most people will use `apps.git` for the folder name of a bare repo).
2. Create a bare repo a second way - this is actually required for many Git services (like Github)

   - Init the `app` repo, but don't actually create a commit
   - Init the `apptest` repo, and commit something
   - Add the `app` repo as a remote manually: `git remote add origin /var/www/app`
   - Push to origin: `git push origin`
3. Use the configuration variables as in the error message above to ignore this situation
4. Do some other funky things to get around this situation.

   - For example, you could go into `app`, and checkout the initial commit (using the hash, rather than `master`).  At this point, since `master` isn't checked out, you can push from `apptest` okay.

Of course, the best solution is probably #1 here (you are just trying to test out Git, after all).  When you create a central repo on a service like Github, they will **only** create a bare repo.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried with option 2, however it fails :/

    `git push origin
    fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
    To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

        git push --set-upstream origin master


    git push --set-upstream origin master        
    To /var/www/test/app
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
    error: failed to push some refs to '/var/www/test/app'`

Comment: Hmm, I duplicated both option 1 and 2 on my PC and they worked okay.  It looks like the remote (/var/www/test/app) is still saying `master` is currently checked out, which implies you already have a commit there.  If you do a `git version`, what is the response?  (The other thing I'd recommend is try #1..)